# llvm-config on Windows

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, llvm, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I'm building a compiler in Rust based on LLVM IR, and I'm using [Inkwell](https://github.com/TheDan64/inkwell) as a wrapper around LLVM C bindings (i.e. [llvm-sys](https://crates.io/crates/llvm-sys)). When I'm building my codebase on WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) with LLVM installed (using the [script suggested by llvm-sys](https://apt.llvm.org/)) everything works fine, but I also want to compile it on Windows (MSVC).

I found out that binaries for Windows attached to official LLVM releases lack `llvm-config.exe`, which is required by llvm-sys, so I tried compiling LLVM from sources. I followed both of this tutorials: [Getting Started](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html) (i.e. used Ninja to compile) and [Getting Started using Visual Studio](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html). In both cases, the compilation was successful and `llvm-config.exe` was properly created and working (i.e. printed help message when run), but when I tried compiling my own project (using `cargo build`), every time I got a linker error: **"linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1120"**, followed by a list of C functions that Inkwell was trying to call, but the linker couldn't find.

I'm pretty sure the reason for this is that something's wrong with my LLVM installation, but I have no idea what, and I couldn't find anything useful anywhere (the closest I found is [this issue](https://github.com/TheDan64/inkwell/issues/278), but it wasn't helpful, because compiling with CMake still makes the compilation of my program exit with code 1120).

**EDIT**:

I managed to fix this issue by adding an additional flag for CMake when building LLVM. Essentially, CMake automatically recognizes your host architecture in the process, but it can confuse *i686* with *x86_64*. Because I compiled my Rust application to *x86_64*, there was a mismatch between my application and the installed LLVM, which resulted in linking errors. Specifying `LLVM_HOST_TRIPLE` in the CMake invocation fixed the problem. The final version looked like this: `cmake -S llvm -B build -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel -DLLVM_HOST_TRIPLE="x86_64-pc-windows-msvc" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\some\path" -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON`.

*Note: When using Inkwell, it is also important that you don't specify `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD`, as it results in linker errors for the omitted architectures.*